# Find Range of Current Calculation's Cell

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 2013

Goal: Without a string search, is it possible to find the cell address of the cell currently being calculated

```
Function AddStuff(Val as integer)
    AddStuff = Val + 5
    if AddStuff > 10 then AddStuff = Active.Address
End Function
```

Lets say we have a table that we fill with formula AddStuff() how do we make **Active.Address** a real thing? The address of the current cell that's being calculated, not the cell that's being referenced in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Application.Caller`:

```
Function AddStuff(Val As Integer)
    AddStuff = Val + 5
    If AddStuff > 10 Then AddStuff = Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

[image]